# System crash with kern.log filled with ^@^@^@^@

Tags: crash, log

My 17.10 (and previous 17.04) system crashes at random time points (usually every 1-2 hours). This only occurs when I work, i.e. if the system is idle I've never noticed it crash. I've looked at the `/var/log/kern.log` and there isn't anything obvious there but there is a weird section that I highly suspect to be part of the issue:

```
Oct 29 08:00:13 kernel: [   15.402318] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
Oct 29 08:00:38 kernel: [   40.459098] Could not find key with description: [97af9771c4694fe8]
Oct 29 08:00:38 kernel: [   40.459111] process_request_key_err: No key
Oct 29 08:00:38 kernel: [   40.459112] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [97af9771c4694fe8]
Oct 29 08:00:38 kernel: [   40.459113] One or more global auth toks could not properly register; rc = [-2]
Oct 29 08:00:38 kernel: [   40.459114] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]
Oct 29 08:00:41 kernel: [   43.911276] rfkill: input handler disabled
Oct 29 08:00:42 kernel: [   44.642111] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
Oct 29 08:00:42 kernel: [   44.643657] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
Oct 29 08:00:42 kernel: [   44.649769] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Oct 29 08:21:29 kernel: [    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x42/0x4e1 with crng_init=0
Oct 29 08:21:29 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.13.0-16-generic (buildd@lcy01-02) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)) #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18
:35:14 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.13.0-16.19-generic 4.13.4)
Oct 29 08:21:29 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=0755919f-9c39-453b-8df0-23166246cbae ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Any ideas to what this is and where to start? The system doesn't respond to any of the keyboard commands for [handling crashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash). There is some variability to the crashes, 50% of the crashes I can't move the mouse. I've also noticed that Spotify keeps playing as if everything was fine and dandy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this bug was due to the Nouveau driver used for my GeForce GT 710 card. Since I installed the proprietary drivers this bug stopped appearing. I guess diving into the https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/HangDiagnosis/ could be an alternative but for now I'm just happy that I don't have to restart the computer every 30-60 minutes.